# Java : Singleton class instances in a Web based Application

Tags: java, singleton

I have this Singleton class inside a Web Application .

```
public class MyDAO 
 {


    private static MyDAO instance;

    private MyDAO() {
    }

    public static MyDAO getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyDAO();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

**I will access it this way**

```
public void get_Data()
{

        MyDAO dao = MyDAO.getInstance();
}
```

How many Objects of MyDAO class will be created  if there are 3 Users accessing the Application ??

Will there be one instance of  MyDAO per User ??

Comment: If multiples threads enter that if condition then it will be instantiated multiple times. It's not threadsafe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must synchronize the access to the `getInstance()`. Otherwise some threads might see a not fully initialized version.

More on the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Once you synchronize it there will only be one instance in the `JVM`. No matter how many variables references to the object. But if you are running N servers there will be one instance in each `JVM`. So N instances in total.

You can double check if you are using `Java 5.0` or older:

```
private static volatile MyDAO();
 public synchronized static MyDAO getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyDAO();
    }
    return instance;
```

But if your application always needs an instance you can eagerly instantiate it:

```
private static MyDAO = new MyDAO();
```

But I would go for the `Bill Purge` solution:

```
    private static class MyDAOHolder { 
            public static final MyDAO INSTANCE = new MyDAO();
    }

    public static MyDAO getInstance() {
            return MyDAOHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
```

Comment: Even for Load balancer which is of Sticky type do we need this Synchronized block ?? please specify .

Comment: Synchronized method could be overkill, since you need to synchronize only on creation

Comment: Are you talking about 3 users accessing or 3 java backend running?

Comment: 3 Users accessing the Application which is  deployed on 3 Web Servers as part of clustering process

Answer (score 2):

No, it's one per JVM.  Be careful about thread safety.

I'd read "Effective Java" and follow the recommendations for how to write a singleton properly.  Yours isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

There will only be one, that is the definition of a singleton.

To synchronize the instantiation, to make sure you only return a complete object you want to use:

```
private static Object semaphore = new Object();
public static MyDAO getInstance() {
    synchronized(semaphore)
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyDAO();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```