# JavaEE Singleton on Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, singleton

I am currently developing a web solution using JavaEE. I have a database connection being established through a singleton.

Will a singleton be user specfic, as in a new instance will be created for each user or will the singleton be shared across all users on the server?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545134/java-singleton-class-instances-in-a-web-based-application

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton object is same for all users. Only one object will be created per application and all users will reach the same singleton object.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton, if implemented properly, means there will be one instance of that class per JVM. Check out [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for a nice overview with code examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'd give you an upvote but don't have enough rep. This answer was good too but Salih replied first!